# Glitches in portal 2

Tags: portal-2

While I can't play Portal 2 right now, I found [this](http://kotaku.com/5803335/so-portal-2s-co+op-mode-only-really-needs-one-person), which demonstrates that most portal 2 co-op chambers need only one person to solve the puzzle, using some glitches. In that video, there's several interesting glitches, including [reportal glitch](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=rW6gQu9Q7dE&feature=player_embedded&t=66), [TRT](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=rW6gQu9Q7dE&feature=player_embedded&t=247), and [this awesome glitch](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=rW6gQu9Q7dE&feature=player_embedded&t=498).
When I first played Portal 2, I was disappointed because [many glitches](http://speeddemosarchive.com/Portal.html#Portal_PC_1427) in Portal disappeared, and thought that there's no glitch in Portal 2 (and that was totally wrong, as you can see above).

Are there any other glitches in Portal 2? For example, when I was playing Portal 2 co-op, I found that there are some glitch about gel, so I could step on blue gel which was blocked by a wall.

Comment: The attribute isn't "at=", it's "&t="

Comment: It is supposed to be '&t=', but 'at=' seems to work for me.

Comment: YouTube supports both, or perhaps the browsers don't...

Comment: Apparently, I've been using TRT without knowing it was a glitch all along.

Comment: "I was disappointed because may glitches in Portal had disappeared"...  Why would you be disappointed that the game had been improved?

Comment: @GnomeSlice Actually I thought about that myself when I'm writing that... Yes, you're right, it's good that game had been improved, but glitches makes the game more... uh... dynamic.

Comment: You can actually play through every chamber of Portal 2 Co-op with only one person and without using glitches. I know this because I've done it.

Comment: @Keaanu sure you can, it's called noclip.

Comment: @Alain Two Xbox controllers actually. One in each hand.

Comment: @Keaanu Touché!

Comment: @Keaanu Without cheats or `ss_map`? :P

Comment: @JiminP Yeah, just a straight-up playthrough. Took about as long as the single-player campaign.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

'Portal Standing' and 'Peek-a-Portal' don't work the same as they did before, but the same effects can still be achieved.

Here's something cool done in P2 with **Peek-a-Portal**:

Here, while peeking through the orange portal to the blue side he is able to place another blue portal from the blue side while moving back to the orange side. Just like Peek-a-Portal from Portal 1.

As for **Portal Standing**, you can't use the ledge of a portal as a place to stand even while switching portal locations, but by carefully jumping through a portal and back, placing a new portal in between. You can jump from your blue portal, to orange, place a blue, and come back out the new blue side, even if there's no way to touch ground on the orange side. An example can be seen in at [0:09](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ZziFnNroWEA&t=09s) of this level 5 speed-run:

A bit later in that same video, there's a third glitch you haven't mentioned yet, guy uses something he describes as "**Portal change cube grab**". It takes him 3 tries, but basically, he switches the location of the blue portal just as the cube is falling through the blue portal, and he's able to grab the cube as it's leaving the orange portal but before it's launched away. Maybe this isn't a glitch, because the mechanics make perfect sense, you just have to be really fast. It probably wasn't an intended solution though.